# Array modifier with offset animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm animating the End Mapping value of a curve and I wanted to array them, that's not the problem. The problem is that I want to animate the End Mapping value with one or two frames offset one instance from the next, and I don't know if it's even possible to.

I could do it manually, it wouldn't take too long, but it's just so I can save the technique for later use.

Maybe Geometry Nodes is the way to go here.

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F4HCDTtLRgXOEcGLq6Yn4-h5jQFLvZbj/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: I can't share the exact .blend file for privacy issues but I can share a new one with the same objects in concept.

Comment: Have you heard about the addon called Commotion? It may be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, sorry. You want _all_ of those curves to map shorter or longer along their own length? Or morph the straight ones to the curved ones?

Comment: I've checked it out and it seems like the Commotion addon works perfectly. I'll answer the question myself, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using geometry nodes. But in this case, you have to remove array modifier, mapping and beveling of the curve and re-build all of that inside GN:

[image]

Integer value gets frame number by driver. You can get it by typing `#frame` in field. Or use Blender 3.1 time node.

It might be difficult to build a round array, as in your example, use the Rotation input for that:

[image]

Comment: i just wonder if this is also possible without trim curve - but with really "changing" the curve points... but nice solution anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion by mqbaka mqbaka.

[The Commotion addon](https://github.com/mrachinskiy/commotion) is probably the best way to offset any kind of animations, this also includes Start and End Mapping in curves.